# Why does linking libm to library require linking libm to executable using my library?

Tags: c, static-linking

I am writing a library. I have the following structure:

```
src/
├── Logger
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Logger.c
│   ├── Logger.h
├── Task
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Task.c
└── ThreadPool
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Thread.c
    ├── Thread.h
    ├── ThreadPool.c
    ├── ThreadPool.h
```

The CMakeLists.txt are very simple. I have a Top-Level CMakeLists.txt where I include these. So I get a static library for everything. Then I search for all object files and combine them to an libsomething.a file. (Not the best way to do it for now but I like cmake but need to learn more about compiling to understand the give functionality of cmake)

This works well an fits my needs BUT I need to link against libm if a compile an executable with my library and I really don't know why. I assume that this happens because I compile a static library without using libm.a or why?

I want the enduser just to link agains my library so he don't has to link agains other non libc parts. And I was not able to find any helpful information about this.

Comment: If we can be a little bit picky, I think `libm` counts as part of the standard library, it's an implementation detail that you have to link it manually on some platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is equivalent to linking with all the individual object files from the library.

As such, the static library have no information about dependencies or other libraries needed. A static library isn't even linked, the object files are just added to the archive.

That's why you need to explicitly link with the dependencies of the static library yourself.

Comment: +Rep. Thanks for make this point clear to me. I extracted the object files from libm and included the needed file. No the best way but it helps to keep my library small.

Comment: @4c1d I'm sorry but that's the wrong way to solve your problem! You should list the dependencies and then it's up to the users of your library to link with the required requirements. Especially for standard compiler-supplied libraries like the math library.

Comment: I thought about it a little bit but not tested it yet. Am I going to have an error if someone using my code is linking against libm? I guess because lrint (the only function I am using) is already defined?